# How to clear an object of the session scoped managed bean?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am developing a login based application in JSF with primefaces. In that I kept the logged user info in session scoped managedbean and I need to clear that details when he logged out, So How to clear those details which are in SessionScoped ManagedBean object?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to invalidate the current session by calling the following function in your action method:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

Also, as the session scoped beans are trashed buring the subsequent request, be sure to send a redirect:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/login.xhtml");
```

Or, simply return a navigation case outcome from your method:

```
return "login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

In case you don't want to invalidate the session and, effectively, retaining your session scoped beans (which is a bad practice in my opinion), just nullify all of the user data (which was hopefully collected in one session scoped managed bean) in the logout method (you may need to inject that bean in case the logout method resides in another session scoped bean).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to clear session scoped managed bean manually. Just clear the user session.
By using following code in servlet for logout.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    System_Properties system_Properties=new System_Properties();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        request.getSession().invalidate();            
    }finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

If you still manually clear the managed bean data then it can be done by using following code.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("managed_bean_name", null);
```

Where "mananged_bean_name" is name of your managed bean.

Hope it helps

Answer (score -3):

When the user logout, the session is destroyed and all the SessionScoped ManagedBean objects too

Comment: A "logout" is not per definition "session destroyed". However, the other way round usually indeed is.

Comment: I do not agree. Logout means usualy "session invalidation". It is the best practice and it is the common pattern. Not destroying the session creates security issue

Comment: Uh, sure. If that was the case, the OP would not have asked this question in first place :)

Comment: Also, *usually* is the odd word in your statement. Destroying the session *always* destroys the beans (user manager included), but on *logout* you *may* destroy beans, invalidate session, do some other job, etc. - because it is a *custom* action. What you do input in the meaning - that is the result. However, this is really a best practice.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I consider too much my own experience and not enough the OP one and is need :)